# Create a Differential backup using SQLPS

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sqlps

I have created a FULL database backup using the following:

```
Backup-SQLDatabase -ServerInstance $sqlServer -Database $db.name -BackupFile $fullBackupFilePath -BackupAction Database
```

I cannot find anywhere specifying the correct -BackupAction for a Differential Backup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This page](http://www.pythian.com/blog/pillars-powershell-sql-server-part-1/) mentions that in SQL 2012 and above there is an -Incremental switch for doing differential backups.